# Редирект nginx если есть параметры get

Tags: nginx, редирект, http-status-code-301

Есть сайт, на котором много раз встречается определенный get параметр, подскажите как сделать 301 редирект на nginx на страницы без этих параметров.

С

```
site.ru/sffefef/efefefefeef.html/?param_a=1
```

На

```
site.ru/sffefef/efefefefeef.html/
```

Пробую так

```
if ($param_a = 1) {
  rewrite (.*)$ $uri permanent;
}
```

Пишет сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз

Answer (score 2):

Решение вопроса:

```
if ($param_a = 1) {
      rewrite (.*)$ $uri? permanent;
}
```

Если после $uri поставить "?" то nginx убирает все  get параметры

Answer (score -1):

На самом деле всё очень просто. Попробуйте следующий код:

```
if ($param_a == 1) {
  rewrite (.*)$ $uri permanent;
}
```

Обратите внимание на первую строку. В вашем случае:

```
if ($param_a = 1)
```

Всегда верно, т.к. true возвращается к тому, что присваивание произошло успешно.

Вам нужно всего лишь добавить один символ "=" для того, чтобы условие начало не присваивание, а сравнение.

```
if ($param_a == 1)
```

Comment: Вы точно с PHP не путаете?

Comment: Пробовал так, Nginx выдает ошибку на ==

Comment: Сорян, перепутал с РНР